# how to rectify inline script issues in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a google chrome extension for reading mail using google gmail api and i get the code for reading mail from google's api page and it was working as a normal html page but when i try to make a extension ,it was not working and throws an error of inline script not allowed.Even when I run it as a normal html page shows error if the script and html was separated as 2 individual files

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. You should also visit the [ask] page and take the [tour].

Comment: I am develop a gmail api for chrome extension, but extension is not accepted inline javascript how to solve this problem